# event fired by a future loaded element

Tags: jquery, selector, future

I have a form thats loads an image. 
I need to do a function that is been called by the image Onclick Event.

The problem is that the selector ( I'm using jQuery) can't find the image id, because when the function is loaded the image wasn't yet there.

SOLUTION :

After the image upload  -->

```
$("#"+foto_nom).bind({
       click:function(){
       alert(this.id); }
 });
```

Binding an event is the solution.

Comment: you selfsolved it, really?!

Comment: yes I did. @roasted I've been lucky this time hahahaha

Comment: anyway, consider to accept @bodrovis answer and upvote him. And next time read docs...  ;)

Comment: @JonathanNaguin why do you give to my question -1 points, how can I know the duplication if I don't know about .on()  ???? Please take off  that negative point.

Comment: @Blackersoul you can get rid off this {-1} points by accepting and upvoting the helper's answer

Comment: @Blackersoul simple search in Google: http://bit.ly/11aqSRI

Comment: The Id of the image is not always the same, so that was another problem in addition. @roasted    Of course before askig I always read and search in the net.... ¬¬

Comment: @Blackersoul then use class instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use 'on' method to attach event to selectors that are not present during page load. Like this:

```
   $(document).on('click', '#id_of_your_image', function(e) {
    //your code here
    });
```

<s>**update**</s>

Binding event to the image after it has been added does not seem to be a good solution.

Comment: *"Binding event to the image after it has been added does not seem to be a good solution."* Why not? Of course it is dangerous to bind multiple event on one element, but if you are carefull with that, on click, it is actually faster than `.on()`.