# jquery on future element click not firing

Tags: jquery

I have the new jquery-1.11.1.min.js I am setting up a click event on a class called '.drop' way before drop exists but it wont fire (unless the element was there at page load). I thought because of migrating from .bind and .click to .on there would be lots on google but I'm finding mostly old things.

google search:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+on+future+click+body+div&oq=jquery+on+future+click+body+div&aqs=chrome..69i57.14483j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

I found this [jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated) and this [event fired by a future loaded element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407129/event-fired-by-a-future-loaded-element)

but my code is the same as the answers and still it does nothing

I have a div.btn on the page at the start

Javascript:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn',function(){//this does happen!
    $('body').append('<div class="drop"></div>');
    });

$('body').on('click','.drop',function(e){console.dir(e);});//this never happens
```

Comment: create jsFiddle please .Share htML

Comment: Jeezes, replace `.body` with `body`, it's not a class but a tagName. Closing .. typo !!!

Comment: Now you've fixed it, but you didn't close the click function properly, syntax error !

Comment: And it works fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/V9Nap/**

Comment: my jsfiddle works???? http://jsfiddle.net/8yLrW/

Comment: syntax error, thanks adeneo +1

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have `class="body"` I believe you are wanting the `<body>` tag which makes your current selector invalid...remove the dot

```
$('body')
```

Make sure `body` exists when code is run

Comment: oops my bad!! I don't have that dot in my code. I have removed it from my question well spotted thank you ('.body' is now 'body' as it should be!). ps: 'body' exists as this is waay after document ready. +1 btw